# How to debug segmentation faults hardware issue?

Tags: hardware-failure, segmentation-fault

this story begins in 2011 when I purchased my Home WorkStation. Back then I was using windows and several BSOD made me switch to Ubuntu.

From time to time ubuntu prompted me "App crashed" notification so I decided to run memtest which showed RAM issues.

I then decided to change RAM but the issue still remained. Since then I also swapped:

1. RAM (Again)
2. Several HD
3. Power Supply
4. GPU
5. Power Supply
6. Misc such as keyboard, headphones, mouse

Since `segfault` seems to be VERY frequent nowadays I also decided to swap the motherboard (it was one of the very few pieces I didn't swap already). Guess what? Still segfaults.

Apart from the Cabinet, the CPU is the only "untouched" element of my home computer but, at this point, I think I need more than a "hunch" to go and spend several hundred of bucks.

So here some dmesg output:
[image]

Other infos:

- When the first segfault happens, other several segfaults are likely to happen,
- CPU is i7 3770,
- CPU temperature is <50 °C,
- Current Mounted Ram is: 4 x CMY32GX3M4A1600C9 (8GB Vengeance PRO series)

Comment: Have you enabled "safe" settings in the BIOS? You could try removing the GPU and run with the i7 on-chip graphics. Also,  run with half the memory, then the other half if the problem persists. If only one half has the problem, then reverse the order of the memory slots. These are not solutions, but means of isolating the problem. If and when you find a stable configuration, restore the original configuration one element at a time to see when the problem recurs.

Comment: @AFH never heard of `safe` setting in BIOS. Will check but both motherboards had this issue. I'll try though. thanks.

Talking about GPU. Why in hell would GPU cause this?

Comment: It is not necessarily called safe settings (hence my quotes), but every BIOS I have worked with has the option to set conservative defaults. I don't know how, but I have had some very peculiar errors as a result of a faulty graphics card, with no obvious relationship with the GPU.

Comment: what is the result of **uname -r**